# How to position numeric in-between values in a heatmap with categorical ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to add to a heatmap the min, max, medium and median values of the same data that is the foundation for the heatmap. Is there a possible way to do this without post-processing of the figure in Illustrator/...?

My code so far is:

```py
# import of libraries
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframe
df_dynEFs = pd.DataFrame()

# read data and write into dataframe
df_dynEFs = pd.read_csv('dynEFs_data.csv')
df_dynEFs.head()

# pivot long table into wide table
df_dynEFs = df_dynEFs.pivot("Impact Factor Value", "Year", "Value")

# draw heatmap
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(df_dynEFs, annot=False, linewidth=.5, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=43, ax=ax)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
ax.tick_params(axis=u'x', which=u'both',length=0)
```

Which yields the following figure:
[image: heatmap so far]

Now I would like to add further data, namely min, max, medium and median values. Some sample data for that additional information could be the following:

```
Year,min,max,medium,median
2015,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
2016,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
2017,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
2018,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
2019,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
2020,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
2021,0.15,0.7,0.53,0.56
```

The y-axis on the left should be visually the same for the heatmap as well as the additional information of the data (though, this could also achieved by using an auxilliary y-axis on the right and afterwards hide this axis?). I imagine it something like this:
[image: heatmap vision]

Does anyone have an idea how to obtain this in Python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your y values are categorical, but your min, max and median comes from outside those values.  You could interpolate the positions of the categories to place the numerical values. Note that this supposes the categories are nicely ordered and none is missing.

Comment: Hey, thanks! The prerequisite of nicely ordered and complete categories is fulfilled. Do you maybe have an idea (or possibly a link) on how to conduct the interpolation you proposed and how to proceed after that with the placement of the numerical values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.interp(values, tick_values, tick_label_values)` to convert the numeric values to their position given the categorical ticks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

factors = np.arange(5, 80, 10) / 100
years = np.arange(2015, 2022)
df_dynEFs_long = pd.DataFrame({"Impact Factor Value": np.repeat(factors, len(years)),
                               "Year": np.tile(years, len(factors)),
                               "Value": np.random.randint(0, 50, len(years) * len(factors))})
df_dynEFs = df_dynEFs_long.pivot(index="Impact Factor Value", columns="Year", values="Value")
df_stats = pd.DataFrame({'Year': years,
                         'min': np.random.randint(10, 20, len(years)) / 100,
                         'max': np.random.randint(60, 80, len(years)) / 100,
                         'medium': np.random.randint(50, 55, len(years)) / 100,
                         'median': np.random.randint(55, 60, len(years)) / 100})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
sns.heatmap(df_dynEFs, annot=False, linewidth=.5, cmap="Blues", vmin=0, vmax=43, ax=ax)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', length=0)
ax.tick_params(rotation=0)

year_ticks = ax.get_xticks()
factor_ticks = ax.get_yticks()
for column in df_stats.columns[1:]:
     ax.scatter(x=year_ticks,
                y=np.interp(df_stats[column], factors, factor_ticks),
                marker='x' if column == 'medium' else '_', s=200, lw=5,
                color='gold' if column in ['min', 'max'] else 'crimson',
                label=column)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.16, 1.01))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with numeric positioned scatter plot]