# Plot labeled points over heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, scatter-plot

I have a heatmap and want to plot certain labeled points over the heatmap. The result should look something like this:

[image: heatmap with dots]

This figure is obtained with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Create DataFrame with the heatmap data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 1.1, 2.1, 2.1],
    'y': [1.4, 2.4, 1.4, 3.4, 2.4, 3.4],
    'value': [9, 8, 1, 0, 6, 2]
})

# Sort the DataFrame for the heatmap
df = df.pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='value')

# Plot the heatmap
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(df, annot=False, cmap='viridis')

# Create DataFrame with point data
points = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1.8, 2.1],
    'y': [2.3, 1.0]
})

# Get the axis labels
x_labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
x_tick_start = x_labels[0].get_position()[0]
x_label_start = float(x_labels[0].get_text())
x_tick_end = x_labels[len(x_labels)-1].get_position()[0]
x_label_end = float(x_labels[len(x_labels)-1].get_text())
y_labels = ax.get_yticklabels()
y_tick_start = y_labels[0].get_position()[1]
y_label_start = float(y_labels[0].get_text())
y_tick_end = y_labels[len(y_labels)-1].get_position()[1]
y_label_end = float(y_labels[len(y_labels)-1].get_text())

# Convert scatter points to heatmap grid coordinates
points['x_new'] = points['x'].apply(lambda x: ((x - x_label_start) * (
    x_tick_end - x_tick_start)) / (x_label_end - x_label_start) + x_tick_start)
points['y_new'] = points['y'].apply(lambda y: ((y - y_label_start) * (
    y_tick_end - y_tick_start)) / (y_label_end - y_label_start) + y_tick_start)

# Plot the scatter dots
ax.scatter(x=points['x_new'], y=points['y_new'], color='black')

# Add scatter labels
for i, row in points.iterrows():
    plt.text(row['x_new']+0.04, row['y_new']+0.05, i+1)

plt.show()
```

Is there a better way to plot the points on the heatmap?

Comment: Are your x and y values for the heatmap always successive integers starting at 1? If not, it might be easier to use `plt.imshow(...., extent=[x0,x1,y0,y1])`.  Seaborn's `sns.heatmap` always creates "categorical" x and y axes, internally numbered `0, 1, 2, ...`. In your example code, you'd just need to subtract `1` for x and for y to position text and scatter points.

Comment: Related: [How to position numeric in-between values in a heatmap with categorical ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74812604/how-to-position-numeric-in-between-values-in-a-heatmap-with-categorical-ticks). Or with `imshow`: [How to show data points on top of matplotlib imshow contour plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74812604/how-to-position-numeric-in-between-values-in-a-heatmap-with-categorical-ticks)

Comment: They are not successive integers, usually they are floats.

Comment: If they aren't equidistant, you need `ax.pcolor(...)` instead of `sns.heatmap(...)`. Alternatively, you could create a filled contour plot from unordered points. Like `ax.tricontourf(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], z=df['value'])` using the original dataframe. To be tested with a larger set of points, as only 6 values is too small for a useable contour plot.

Comment: The link to the ´imshow´ answer gave me a good hint. I am now able to generate the result wanted. Maybe there is a better way to scale the points properly, but it works for now.

Comment: `imshow()` with `extent=...` is a good way to scale the points, provided that your x and y values are equidistant.  The "best" approach varies based on your specific data and requirements.